# building from latest source as well older pspp is unable to compile after upgrade to ubuntu 21.04 from, 20

Tags: undefined

building from latest source as well older pspp is unable to compile after upgrade to ubuntu 21.04 from, 20

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_uri_split_network'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_uri_is_valid'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_memdup2'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_uri_join'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_uri_split_with_user'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_spawn_async_with_pipes_and_fds'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_file_set_contents_full'
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libgio*
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo rm libgio*

sudo apt-get install libgio*
```